# Asymptotic distribution of OLS prediction

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Let's say we have the usual linear model $$Y = \beta^{T}X + \varepsilon,$$

where $Y \in \mathbb{R}, X \in \mathbb{R}^p, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}, \varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Furthermore $Y \sim N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$ and $X \sim N(0,\Sigma)$. Suppose that we have centered data without intercept. The OLS estimator is $$\hat{\beta} = \left(X^T X \right)^{-1}X^T Y = \beta + \left(X^T X \right)^{-1}X^T \varepsilon.$$

We already know that CLT says (with some assumptions) $$\sqrt{N} \left(\hat{\beta} - \beta \right) \sim N\left(0, \sigma^2 \left(N^{-1}X^T X\right)\right)$$ if $N \rightarrow \infty.$

Now I wonder, let's say $X_N$ is a new independent observation of $X$. So $Y_N = \beta^{T}X_N + \varepsilon_N$ and $\widehat{Y}_N = \hat{\beta}^{T}X_N$. What can I say about the distribution of $\sqrt{N} \left(\hat{\beta}^TX_N - \beta^T X_N \right)$?

Comment: You assign a probability distribution to $X,$ but your statement about what CLT says, purporting to give the distribution of $\sqrt N\left( \widehat\beta - \beta \right),$ actually gives the _conditional_ distribution of that random variable _given_ $X,$ so the distribution of $X$ has no bearing---in effect $X$ is treated as constant rather than random.

Comment: @MichaelHardy but the new $X_N$ is independent from the data $X$... I mean, I used my data to find $\hat{\beta}$ and CLT gives me the conditional asymptotic distribution. But now $X_N$ is not an observation from $X$, $X_N$ was not used to find $\hat{\beta}$. Is that make sense now? It chances something?

Comment: ok, So maybe what you want is the conditional distribution of $\sqrt N\left( \widehat\beta - \beta \right)$ given $X$ but not given $X_n.$ Is that it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes. Or even easier, what is $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}X_N)$ given the data $(Y_i,X_i)$ but not given $X_N$?

Comment: If you're given $(Y_i,X_i)$ for all values of $i$ involved in the computation of $\widehat\beta,$ then $\widehat\beta$ becomes a constant for these purposes, then you have $Y_N = \widehat\beta^T X + \varepsilon.$ And $\widehat\beta^T X\sim \operatorname N(0, \text{??})$ and $\varepsilon \sim \operatorname N(0,\sigma^2),$ and those two terms are independent. But what do you put in place of those two question marks? $\qquad$